# Laravel: Can't access methods in Model from Controller

Tags: methods, laravel, models, controllers

I'm having an issue with one of my controllers accessing the methods within a model.

I have a controller (application>controllers>event.php) with an index method:

```php
class Event_Controller extends Base_Controller {
    public $layout = 'layouts.default';
    public $restful = true; 
    public function get_index()
    {   

        $category       = (isset($_GET['category']))? $_GET['category'] : NULL;
        $date           = (isset($_GET['date']))? $_GET['date'] : NULL;
        $county         = (isset($_GET['county']))? $_GET['county'] : NULL;
        $events         = Event::get_event_list($category, $date, $county);

        $this->layout->title = 'Events';
        $this->layout->nest('content', 'event.index', array(
          //'data' => $some_data


    ));
        }
}
```

And the model (application>models>event.php):

```php
class Event extends Eloquent{
    public static function get_event_list($category = null, $month = null, $county = null)
    {
        $events = DB::table('events');

        if($month)      
            $events->where('dtDateTime', 'LIKE', $month.'-%');

        if($category)
            $events->where('strCategories', 'LIKE', '%['.$category.']%');       

        if($county)
            $events->where('strCounty', 'LIKE', '%'.$tag.'%');

        return $events->order_by('dtDateTime', 'DESC')->get();


    }
}
```

If I change the model name in the call to the method in the controller (ie Eventsx::....) I get an error that the model doesn't exist so I know it can find the model, however when I try and run this (or with a call to any other method in the Model), I get the error:

> Call to undefined method Laravel\Event::get_event_list()

I have similar controllers accessing similar methods in their models but for some reason, it is not playing ball here. The controller can access methods in other Models with no issues.

Here are my routes:

```php
Route::get('/events', array('as' => 'event', 'uses' => 'Event@index'));
Route::get('/events/(:any)', array('as' => 'event', 'uses' => 'Event@event'));
```

Can anyone see anything glaringly obvious that I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked it out. class Event is already taken by laravel. I renamed my model and everything worked fine

Comment: You could also use namespaces.